# PHPUnit: можно ли одновременно замокапить и класс, и интерфейс?

Tags: php, phpunit

Дисклеймер: я понимаю, что есть обходные решения данной задачи, но интересует именно наиболее нативный способ реализации.

У нас есть интерфейс, который мы хотим отлавливать через `try catch`. Реальных классов, реализующих этот интерфейс, еще не существует, мы делаем этот отлов только на случай, если библиотека, в которой этот интерфейс реализуется, получит новые классы исключений с этим интерфейсом. В коде, который работает вокруг этого `try catch`, у данного исключения используется метод `getMessage()`.

Соответственно, нам нужно получить мок интерфейса, у которого будет метод `getMessage()`. Просто взять и указать данный метод через `setMethods()` невозможно - `PHPUnit` проверит, есть ли такой метод в интерфейсе, и выдаст ошибку. И в итоге нам нужно получить мод интерфейса с дополнительным методом.

Вопрос: мы можем взять реально существующий класс `Exception`, указать неким образом, что он должен реализовывать наш интерфейс, и получить такой мок? Или нативными средствами `PHPUnit` данная задача не решается?

Comment: Если честно, только половину понял из-то что вы написали. А вообще мокнуть интерфейс можно. И все методы этого интерфейс тоже можно мокнуть и проиграть сценарии, что делает каждый метод, что он должен вернуть или выкинуть Exception

Comment: @ЕвгенийГаврилов можно, но нам нужно мокнуть интерфейс, и при этом иметь в этом моке не только его методы, но и методы некоего класса. Если просто взять и сказать, что я хочу мок такого интерфейса и дайте мне в нем такие методы, то PHPUnit ругнется на те из них, которых в реальном интерфейсе нет.